# Azure Media Services responds with 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: azure, service, azure-media-services

I have a set of videos which I have uploaded via Azure Media Explorer and some via the .NET SDK (Azure Media Services Extensions) in a custom application. I have encoded all with the Media Encoder Standard and the "H264 Multiple Bitrate 720p" preset.

The videos are recordings from a Kinect Sensor (BGRA) and transcoded with ffmpeg to H.264 Base.

When I try to play the videos from the Azure Media Player or from within the Azure Media Services Content Page I get an error message.

Azure Media Player (from my ASP.NET MVC View) gets a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" back from AMS and shows a 0x020200193 error message in the player.

The Azure Media Services Playback from within the Portal throws the following error in the JavaScript console:

```
"VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)" and shows:
```

> The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported

If I try to play the samples from the http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/ websites they all work. If I try to play my videos on the same websites I get an error message as well.

If I browse to the manifest (`http://{myaccountname}.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx}/{xxxx}.ism/Manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)`)

I get the following XML response:

```
<serverError>
<status>403</status>
<subStatus>1000</subStatus>
..
</serverError>
```

I have tried to change the Storage Container Access (Private, Public Container, and Public Blob), the problem persists.

I have tried to create a completely new Azure Media Service Account and Storage Account - same problem.

The strange detail that puzzles me is that I downloaded, built, and ran this sample https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-encode-with-media-encoder-standard/ on the exact same AMS account / Storage Account and the same AMP instance the video plays correctly, and so does the AMS Playback from within the portal.

How do I troubleshoot this? Is this an authentication issue or is this in fact a media format problem? The fact that the BigBuckBunny.mp4 video from the above mentioned article plays from the same account with the same configuration makes me think this is a format issue?

Comment: can you share a manifest url with ampinfo@microsoft.com?

Comment: Also, can you check if you have at least 1 streaming reserved unit. You can do this with the Azure Media Explorer tool. Click on the "Steaming Endpoints" tab you have put your credentials in. Click the streaming endpoint you are using and ensure that the "ScaleUnits" is at least 1.

Comment: I am positive I had a streaming reserved unit during testing, will send the manifest url (just need to start the service again)

Comment: Did you solved the issue? I have the same problem and don't know where is the issue.